# Formula to calculate the coordinates of some points on a circle

Tags: circles, coordinate-systems

Given the following variables

- $a$ : the number of points proportionally spread on a circle
- $(O_x, O_y)$ : the origin of the circle
- $\theta$ : the angle separating the points i.e. $360/a$
- $r$ : the radius of the circle

how to get the coordinates of each point?

Here is an illustration with three points, i.e. $a = 3$ and $\theta = 120$
**NOTE:** The $(x, y)$ axis is clockwise.

---

[image: Illustration of equally spread points on a circle in a clockwise axis]

---

Comment: @emilionovati @gabielecassese @cansomeonehelpmeout . There are some differences in the answers which bother me. some use `-` in the `y` coordinate part and others use `+`. also, some use degrees while others use radians. I'm confused.

Comment: Using degrees or radians here doesn't matter. $\pm$ in front of $y$ determines if you're going around the circle clockwise ($+$), or counter-clockwise ($-$).

Comment: ok. got it all. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle separating point has to be $\frac{2\pi}{a}$ (using radians). 
Using the definition of $\sin$ and $\cos$ (and assuming that the first point has $\theta=0$), translating the points from the origin to the centre of the circle and applying a simmetry on the x-axis, we get the following:

Given the number $a$, you have:
$p_i=\left(O_x+r\cos\left(\frac{2i\pi}{a}\right),O_y-r\sin\left(\frac{2i\pi}{a}\right)\right)$, where $p_i$ is the i-th point, and $0\leq i<a$.

I assumed that the passages should be easily understandable without the explicit calculation, if it is not the case I will insert them

Comment: easily understood. kudos

Answer (score 2):

If your first point on the circle (lying on the line parallel to the $x$-axis) is $P_0=(O_x+r,O_y)$ then the next point (moving counter-clockwise) is $P_1=(O_x+r\cos(\frac{360}{a}),O_y-\sin(\frac{360}{a}))$.

Each time the angle increases by $\frac{360}{a}$ degrees, so more generally:

$$P_n=(O_x+r\cos\left (\frac{360n}{a}\right), O_y-r\sin\left (\frac{360n}{a}\right))$$ for $0\leq n\leq a-1$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

center the circe at the origin and use the parametric equation of the circle:

$$
(x,y)=(r\cos t, r\sin t)
$$

($t$ is the angle at the origin)

---

If the center of the circle is at $(x_0,y_0)$ the parametric equation becomes 
$$
(x,y)=(x_0+r\cos t,y_0+ r\sin t)
$$
and the searched points are given by the values $t=n \theta$ for $n=1,2,\cdots, a$, (and your $\theta$)

Comment: do you mean $t$ is $\theta$? Well, about centering the circle at the origin, I can't. It has to stay that way.

Comment: I added to my answer. I hope it's useful !