# know the equation of a circle in space (3D), how to get the coordinates of n-equal points on the circle

Tags: circles, 3d

Know the equation of a circle in space as:
$(x - x_{0})^{2} + (y - y_{0})^{2} + (z - z_{0})^{2} = r^{2},\quad
a(x - x_{0}) + b(y - y_{0}) + c(z - z_{0}) = 0$. 
That is known the center $p = (x_{0}, y_{0}, z_{0})$, the radius $r$ and the normal vector $n = (a, b, c)$.
The circle is equally divided by n points on the circle, how to get the coordinates of each point?
A similar 2-D question has been solve: [Formula to calculate the coordinates of some points on a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2655567/formula-to-calculate-the-coordinates-of-some-points-on-a-circle)
How can we solve it for the 3-D case?

Comment: Welcome to MSE; you've written a nice clear question here; keep up the good work. One thing is missing, though: Unless you give me a *first* point on the circle, there are infinitely many solutions to your problem --- just take any one solution, and then rotate the circle a tiny bit to get another. You might want to either specify a known point, or say that finding a first point is part of the problem. Anyhow, nice question, and keep up the good work!

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Find the direction $u$ towards one point $q_0$ on the circle. To do this, look at $a,b,c$, and determine which is the smallest in absolute value. If it's $a$, then we're going to make a vector that looks like $(0, s, t)$; if it's $b$, we're going to make a vector that looks like $(s, 0, t)$; if it's $c$, we're going to make a vector that looks like $(s, t, 0)$. Let's take a concrete example: $(a, b, c) = (3, -2, 4)$. Then $|b|$ is the smallest, so we'll look for a vector of the form $(s, 0, t)$.

To find this vector, we take $(a, b, c)$ and make the chosen entry $0$ (in our example, we now have $(3, 0, 4)$), then swap the other two entries, negating the first. In our example, this gets us $(-4, 0, 3)$. Call this vector $w$.

Now compute $u = r \cdot \frac{1}{\|w\|} w$.

Then (this takes a little proof), (1) the point $p + u$ is on the plane defined by $\{X \mid n \cdot (X - p) = 0 \}$, and (2) the point $p + u$ is distance $r$ from $p$, so it's also on the circle.

Step 2: Let $v = \frac{1}{\|n\|} n \times u$. $v$ again lies in the plane, just like $u$, and is perpendicular to $u$, and has the same length as $u$ (namely $r$).

Step 3: Define, for $k = 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots, n-1$, 
$$
q_k = p + \cos (\frac{2\pi k}{n}) u +  \sin (\frac{2\pi k}{n}) v.
$$
Then the points $q_0, q_1, \ldots, q_{n-1}$ are equally spaced around your circle.

Comment: How to randomly find a first point on the circle?

Comment: For (a,b,c), 1.If two of the three values have the same absolute value and are the smallest, for example, |a|=|b|<|c|, is it the same when using either (0,s,t) or (s,0,t) to make vector in step1? 2. If |a|=|b|=|c|, is it the same for using (0,s,t) or (s,0,t) or (s,t,0) to make vector?

Comment: If you want the first point on the circle to be random, change the formula for $q_k$ to be $q_k = p + \cos (g + \frac{2\pi k}{n}) u +  \sin (g + \frac{2\pi k}{n}) v$, and then pick $g$ (once and for all, before you construct the points) to be a number uniformly chosen between $0$ and $2\pi$. .

Comment: If two (or all three) of the points have the smallest absolute value, you can safely pick any of them, and the algorithm will still work. All I'm doing is constructing a *nonzero* vector  ("nonzero" is ensured by removing the smallest element -- at least one of the other two must be nonzero, or $n = (a,b,c)$ couldn't be a plane normal!) that's orthogonal to $n$ (which I do through the swap-and-negate trick).

Comment: Many thanks. I don't understand step3. Through step1 and step2, we obtain two perpendicular vectors in the circle plane with length as r, could you please give more explanation for step3?

Comment: Sure. Suppose (for $k = 0, 1..., n-1)$, you took $q_k = (0,0,0) + \cos (\frac{2\pi k}{n}) (1,0,0) +  \sin (\frac{2\pi k}{n}) (0,1,0)$. Can you see why, in that case, you'd get $n$ equally spaced points around the unit circle in the $xy$-plane? (I'm asking this to try to diagnose what you don't understand.)